# MySQL chain multiple "Match Against"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm unable to get this code to work. Any idea how to change that? I tried adding `( )` around the entire condition but that doesn't seem to fix it either.

```
 SELECT * FROM clients WHERE 
        MATCH(LNAME) AGAINST('aaaa') OR
        MATCH(FNAME) AGAINST('aaaa') OR
        MATCH(MAIL) AGAINST('aaaa') OR
        MATCH(TEL) AGAINST('aaaa')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE 
        MATCH(`LNAME`) AGAINST('aaaa') OR
        MATCH(`FNAME`) AGAINST('aaaa') OR
        MATCH(`MAIL`) AGAINST('aaaa') OR
        MATCH(`TEL`) AGAINST('aaaa')
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE MATCH(`LNAME`,`FNAME`,`MAIL`,`TEL`) AGAINST('aaaa');
```

Comment: thank you, this works fine. But have you got any idea why I only get a retun when LNAME, FNAME,... are at minimum 3 characters? can I adjust that?

Comment: @cmplieger the three letter limitation is set by MySQL as default minimum length of a search term for fulltext lookups. Shorter search terms are simply dropped. You can configure the minimum length with MySQL settings `innodb_ft_min_token_size` or `ft_min_word_len` depeding on the storage engine. You need to rebuild your index after changing that setting though. See the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Are you matching all of them against one string?  You can make the query much shorter by combining them.

```
SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE 
    MATCH(`LNAME`,`FNAME`,`MAIL`,`TEL`) AGAINST('aaaa')
```

Answer (score 0):

$srch->consultar("SELECT  * , MATCH ( tecnologia, descriptores, autorTecnologia) AGAINST ('$dato' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS puntuacion  FROM ficha WHERE  MATCH (tecnologia, descriptores, autorTecnologia) AGAINST ('$dato' IN BOOLEAN MODE) HAVING puntuacion > 0.5");

pagination use

$sql=$obj->consultas("SELECT  * , MATCH ( tecnologia, descriptores) AGAINST ('$param' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS puntuacion FROM ficha WHERE  MATCH (tecnologia, descriptores) AGAINST ('$param' IN BOOLEAN MODE) HAVING puntuacion > 0.2 order by puntuacion desc limit $initReg,$TamPag");